# How do I convert this code so that it works in a Batch file?

Tags: ffmpeg

Hey there I'm using FFmpeg for video trimming and I read somewhere that I could just create a batch file rather than entering the respecting directories with the Command Prompt and then be using this code.

```
for %F in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%F" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy "%~nF_trimmed.mp4"
```

Keep in mind that I know nothing about programming. So... can it be done? Is it easy?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for %%F in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%%F" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy "%%~nF_trimmed.mp4"
```